# (Emacs) Brackets aren't indenting correctly

Tags: emacs, indentation, key-bindings

In emacs, when I type this:

```
if(true)
{
```

I get this:

```
if(true)
  {
```

So then I have to press the left arrow to move back one space, then delete the two extra spaces to get the expected result. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What type of buffer or language is that? Maybe you get a better answer here: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check what the `RET` key is bound to in the current mode. Bind it to something else, such as `newline`.

Or just turn off `electric-indent-mode`, by putting this in your init file:

```lisp
(electric-indent-mode -1)
```

That turns off having `RET` (the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key) automatically indent, in most programming modes.